# What is the Trans America Express card for?

Tags: ticket-to-ride

I just got the USA 1910 expansion for the US version of Ticket To Ride.  It comes with a few new cards including "Trans America Express".  What is the Trans America Express card for, and how does one earn it?  (The route on the picture looks really hard!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Trans America Express card replaces the Longest Path card in the original game.**

Giving players a replacement larger set of cards gave the designers license to make a couple changes.  The name change you noted is one.  Also 4 Destination Tickets had their rewards lowered to be in line with the rest of the destinations.